# "WebDriverError: unknown error: no chrome binary at my electronAppFolder/dist/linux-unpacked/app.exe" when running selenium test for electronapp build

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, electron, electron-builder

This is the setup of my selenium test.js file

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const By = webdriver.By;
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer('http://localhost:9515')
  .withCapabilities({
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      binary: 'path-to-electronapp',
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--remote-debugging-port=9222' , '--headless', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']
    }
  })
  .forBrowser('electron')
  .build();
```

I have been trying to test my electron app build with selenium to run it on docker.
I have tried specifying the binary for appimage that gets created after the build in selenium test file.
i have tried specifying the binary for app.exe that gets created after the build but in both cases error remains the same

Comment: @LorenRogers i saw u faced similar issue can you please help with this?